# Native Camera support in adb shell for OpenCV - android

Tags: android, shell, opencv, camera, adb

With the new 2.3rc version of OpenCV, we are able to run executables that use OpenCV in adb shell without dealing with JNI interfaces for android. The new version also comes with prebuilt native camera support. (see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.3.0 for details ) I would like to know if it is possible to capture a preview frame from the camera using an executable that runs run in adb shell. Using the code snippet in the documentation I wrote the following simple code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
const char* message = "Capture a frame!";
const char* errorMessage = "Could not open the camera!";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // print message to console
  printf("%s\n", message);
cv::VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_ANDROID + 0);
//cv::VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_ANDROID + 1);//front camera for Android 2.3.3 or  newer
if( !capture.isOpened() )
{
  printf("%s\n", errorMessage);    
    return 0;
}
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

cv::Mat frame;
capture >> frame;
if( !frame.empty() ){
imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/CaptureFrame.png", frame);
}
return 0;
}
```

(The build scripts are similar to HelloAndroid sample application in the downloaded library)
It builds and runs in adb shell but I cannot capture frame and thus write to the image file. I checked the logcat output and it seems to load the libraries and opens the camera but then it gets stuck at "capture>>frame" step.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Zafer